# php session not working with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

I've got a weird problem were php session variables are not working on pages accessed by ajax.

Server Side Code: **s2.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

    echo '{"response":"'.$_SESSION["email"].'"}';

    exit();
?>
```

Client Side Code: **index.php**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'mysite.com/s2.php',
    data: info,
    error: function() {
        console.log("broke :( ");
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    type: 'POST'
});
```

when I navigate to mysite.com/index.php i see: `{response: ""}` in the console.

When I navigate to mysite.com/s2.php I see `{response: "email@address"}` displayed in the browser.

I just don't understand why **s2.php** can access the session normally but not when run by an ajax call.

Also, when I run it on my home server, everything seems fine. But it's when it's run on my wife's bluehost.com server is when it has problems. Is this something with their settings?

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but have you logged-in to the app on her bluehost server?  Sessions don't span servers.

Comment: @Max at this point I'm thinking I've done something dumb. But yes. **index.php** is on the bluehost server, and it is the page that originally set `$_SESSTION["email"]`

Comment: have you tried setting withCredentials to true?

Comment: @Musa I assume you mean as part of the ajax call? Just tried, no difference.

Comment: According to the http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php official documentation, you must call the `session_start()` method in each one of pages where you are going to use the session, so try to call `session_start()` in your index.php.

Comment: @JoseRojas I have. And I know it's working because the variable is set on index.php and will still work if I navigate to s2.php in the browser. it's only when I access s2.php through ajax that it seems to forget about the session.

Comment: Where are you storing the email from?

Comment: @JoseRojas it's just being created near the top of index.php like `$_SESSION["email"] = "email@address";`

Comment: I'm trying to replicate the issue in my local machine, but it is working exactly as you posted.

Comment: @JoseRojas yeah. that's why I'm thinking there is some kind of setting that's messed up with bluehost. As stated in the question, it works perfect on my home system too. But I just don't know what kind of setting might do that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164798/discussion-between-jose-rojas-and-tyler-mackenzie).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According with the [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php), you must call the `session_start()` method in each one of pages where you are going to use the session, so try to call `session_start()` in your index.php.

This method starts new or resumes existing session, also check your PHPSESSID cookie sent with the AJAX request that match with your index.php PHPSESSID.

Comment: determined that I was viewing the site at `www.mysite.com/` but was making the AJAX call with `mysite.com/s2.php` It determined that as cross-domain and didn't send the PHPSESSID cookie.

Answer (score 0):

something interesting happend to me as i had the same issue, but nothing that i tried worked. It seems that after using [session_regenerate_id()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php) after the login process (to prevent session fixation attacks), the session id was stored as cookie, but not updated to the new session id. The page calling the ajax had one session id , while the ajax php file was using an other.

Clearing the cookies solved the problem.

One thing to check if such problems occur, is if the [session_id()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) is the same on all involved pages, even if [session_start()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) is used on all pages.